# javac not found after set environment variable

Tags: java, windows-7, environment-variables, command-prompt, javac

I am running on a Windows 7 machine.

I installed Java jdk 1.7.

I have set the Path and PATH environment variable to point to the Java jdk 1.7/bin directory.

Executing `java -version` in the command prompt yields Java version 1.7.0_45.

However when I execute `javac` it says that:

> javac is not recognized as an internal or external command

I am really stumped on this problem.  All other threads seem to get similar issues resolved via changing the environment variable but this is not solving my problem in this situation.

### Edit

When I run `java -version` in Console2 it says that the currently used version of Java is 1.6 and I am not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Sharing you PATH variable value is a good idea to have 5his fixed asap.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 \bin

Comment: Sounds like some problem with your path most likely. Try running `where java`. Is the java program being executed from where you expect?

Comment: I've also had trouble in the past when I've had the path set to contain two different version of the same named file. And guessing you know this, but be sure to close the cmd prompt and reopen it whenever you make changes to the path to make sure it follows those changes.

Comment: running from C:\Windows\System32\java.exe 

I am expecting this to have run from program files...... plus it is a 64 bit machine

Comment: `echo %PATH%` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: echo %PATH% yields something rediculously long but the important thing is that C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 \bin; is inside the variable (at the front with a semi-colon) 
echo %JAVA_HOME% returns C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

Comment: FYI I always close and re-open terminal after changing environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause, but in the path you posted

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 \bin

Looks like an extra space in between of "jdk1.7.0_45" and "\bin"

Also it's always good to append ";" at the end.

PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;

Answer (score 0):

Chnage it to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin` and it shall work like magic :)