# Javac not found -- already added bin to PATH

Tags: java, javac

I'm having trouble getting javac to work despite adding its location to the PATH variable. Error below:

```
me@comp-LTW ~
$ javac
-bash: javac: command not found
```

`PATH` below:

```
$ echo $PATH
/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSH/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Symantec/VIP Access Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin: C:/cygwin64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/sbt/bin: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin:/cygdrive/c/texlive/2016/bin/win32:/cygdrive/c/Users/anyoung/AppData/Local/Box/Box Edit: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin:/usr/lib/lapack
```

I have read over the following:

[javac not found after set environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738264/javac-not-found-after-set-environment-variable)

https://kb.iu.edu/d/acar

[How to tell if JRE or JDK is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539779/how-to-tell-if-jre-or-jdk-is-installed)

The goal is to see if I have successfully installed `JDK`. The following seems to show the version of `JRE`, as opposed to `JDK`.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

In a `cmd`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\anyoung>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\anyoung>ECHO.%PATH:;= & ECHO.%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
 C:\cygwin64\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin
 /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin
C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32
C:\Users\anyoung\AppData\Local\Box\Box Edit\
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin
```

Comment: Do you have Windows? Where do you try `javac`? In Cygwin / Git Bash?
What is this `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin` in the same path with this `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows 7. I am trying `javac` in Cygwin. I don't understand your last question. I have updated the original post with the answers to your questions

Comment: Please try `javac -version` in a **cmd**. Does this work? Also, try this `ECHO.%PATH:;= & ECHO.%`.

Comment: @ROMANIA output added to original post

Comment: @user2205916 Perhaps you have not installed a JDK, only a JRE ? There's also an odd space in your PATH in `Edit: C:/Program` and other places.

Comment: You can check that you actually have **javac.exe** in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin` (using Windows Explorer). You don't have to have spaces before those paths, so you can try to edit your PATH and to remove them. Also this Linux-style line `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin` is very strange in a Windows path.

Comment: @nos I installed a JDK: Java SE Development Kit 8u112.

Comment: @ROMANIA I removed those spaces before those paths but that did not resolve the issue. Yes, I do indeed have javac.exe in that directory.

Comment: My last attempt: Open a new **cmd**. Do not use an old one when you test your `javac -version` command.

Comment: @user2205916 Open a new CMD, if you are opening a new CMD from some application (like Windows Explorer), then close that application down  completely and reopen it before creating a new CMD from it.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove done. same result as shared above in the original post.

Comment: @user2205916 Last thing I always do is just kill `explorer.exe` and everything else that seems related..